# Two questions on trigonometric identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> 1. Develop a formula for $\sin \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)$ in terms of $x$.
> 2. Use a double angle formulae to develop a formula for $\sin (4x) $ in terms of $x$.

---

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Could someone please explain what the question is asking, how to solve it? Also, How do I know which trig identity to use for this?  Also  are $x$ and $x/2$ linked angles, or are  in no way linked ?

Comment: I believe they are asking for you to express these in equivalent expressions where the trigonometric functions are have $x$ as the argument, i.e. $\sin x$, $\cos x$, etc. For both problems you have to use the double angle formulas: $\sin(2y)=2\sin(y)\cos(y)$ and $\cos(2y)=\cos^2(y)-\sin^2(y)$

Comment: It's already in terms of $\large x$.

Comment: @user3034084 : if it is really the way the question was worded, it was really poorly worded.  Kevin's guess seems to make sense

Comment: Yes kevin is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

I'll assume that you we're shown that:
$$\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x, \quad \cos 2x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x$$
What happens when you plug in $x \to x/2$? $x \to 2x$?

Comment: Wait what do you mean

Comment: The formula's are true for any real number, whether it be x, y, x/2, etc..